# Problema con manejo de box en React Native con Native Base

Tags: css, typescript, react-native, librería, design

Estoy tratando de implementar una especie de "menu" con complementos Box.
El problema es el siguiente... Al momento de terminar la impresion los Box creados desde botonesHome a lo ultimo se desincroniza notablemente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual hace que el menu siempre quede extraño, como un dato adicional puedo decir que siempre sucede con los 2 ultimos a imprimir.
La idea es que la linea del medio (Que es la separación de los box) quede sincronizada.

Probe forzando un "Width" pero no funciono.

```
const botonesHome = items.map((item, index) => (


    <Box

    w="45%"
    shadow={9}
    _dark={{
      borderColor: 'coolGray.600',
      backgroundColor: 'gray.700',
    }}
    _light={{
      backgroundColor: 'gray.50',
    }}
  >
    <Icon name={item.Icon} size={70} style={{ textAlign: "center" }} />
    <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{item.Titulo}</Text>
  </Box>
  ));

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 100 }}>
      <NativeBaseProvider>
        <HStack space={3} alignItems="center" direction="row" flexWrap="wrap" justifyContent="center">
          {botonesHome}
        </HStack>
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    </View>
  );
};
```